# how to count boolean type field in mongodb aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have aggregated stages with $lookup via $regex. In this code:

I have groups and students collections.

```
Groups: {_id : ObjectId, title: String}
Students{mainGroups: String,isReserved: Boolean}
```

mainGroups is a concatenated string, for all groups, every student has taken in school.

My code is giving me, all students collection for all groups, with however many students are returned.

```
    [
      {
          $addFields: {
              gid: { $toString: "$_id" }
          }
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'students',
            let: { groupId: "$gid" },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $regexMatch: {
                                input: "$mainGroups",
                                regex: { $concat: [".*", "$$groupId", ".*"] },
                                options: "i"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "students"
        }
      },
      {
          $project: {
              _id: 1,
              gid: 1,
              title: 1,
              studentCount: { $size: "$students" }
          }
      }
    ]
```

I want to get totalIsReservedStudents field by $students.isReserved Boolean property in students collection.

I try it get by $group:

```
[
  {
      $addFields: {
          gid: { $toString: "$_id" }
      }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
        from: 'students',
        let: { groupId: "$gid" },
        pipeline: [
            {
                $match: {
                    $expr: {
                        $regexMatch: {
                            input: "$mainGroups",
                            regex: { $concat: [".*", "$$groupId", ".*"] },
                            options: "i"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        as: "students"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      studentCount: { $size: "$students" }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$students._id",
      totalStudents: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      totalStudentsReserved: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: {
            if: {
              $eq: [
                "$isReserved",
                true
              ]
            },
            then: 1,
            else: 0
          }
        }
      },
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        gid: 1,
        title: 1,
        studentCount: 1,
        totalStudents:1,
        totalStudentsReserved:1
    }
  },
]
```

How can I get total amount of reserved students for every groups in totalStudentsReserved?

Comment: Please provide sample documents and the expected results for them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to group inside the `$lookup` pipeline, this will also reduce the amount of data transferred between collections:

```
db.groups.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
      from: "students",
      let: {groupId: {$toString: "$_id"}},
      pipeline: [
        {$match: {$expr: {$regexMatch: {
                input: "$mainGroups",
                regex: {$concat: [".*", "$$groupId", ".*"]},
                options: "i"
        }}}},
        {$group: {
            _id: null,
            count: { $sum: 1},
            isReserved: {$sum: {$cond: ["$isReserved", 1, 0]}}
        }}
      ],
      as: "students"
  }},
  {$project: {
      _id: 1,
      title: 1,
      studentCount: {$ifNull: [{$first: "$students.count"}, 0]},
      isReserved: {$ifNull: [{$first: "$students.isReserved"}, 0]}
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZcIRkGDGm3D)

Nevertheless, concatenating strings is not a good idea for multi group assignment. I suggest you create an array (set) of groups on each student document.

Comment: Thank you very much! It solved my problem!